# org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to send text with the option `sendkeys()`. This is my method case within my class page object:

```
public void setEntityName() {
    internalWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"entity_name\"]")));
    entityName.clear();
    entityName.sendKeys("TEST");
}
```

HTML:

```html
 <input id="entity_name" name="entity_name" type="text" ng-model="entityData.name" ng-disabled="false" placeholder="Type Enity Name" data-maxlength="20" data-smart-validate-input="" data-required="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched">
```

The test is shown the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id="entity_name"]
```

Can anyone help me with this error.

Comment: The error means what it says... it timed out waiting for the element to become visible. That means that either the element (likely) will never become visible or the page is loading really slowly and didn't become visible within the timeout period. We can't say which it is because we don't have access to the page or any more information. My guess is that you've chosen an element that will never become visible, maybe because the locator matches two elements, one for desktop and one for mobile where the mobile element comes first and so matches your locator but will never show on the desktop.

Comment: A suggestion... if you have a locator that only looks for an id, use `By.id()`. It is better supported and faster than `By.xpath()`.

Comment: If I am seeing what the error says, but I wanted to know if they have any suggestions,I have already used By id, when I do the manual test I can write in the input, I can also click on it, but it does not allow me to use the sendKeys the element not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to invoke `sendKeys()` instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  public void setEntityName() {
      WebElement entityName = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-valid-maxlength.ng-touched#entity_name[ng-model='entityData.name']")));
      entityName.clear();
      entityName.sendKeys("TEST");
  }
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  public void setEntityName() {
      WebElement entityName = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched' and @id='entity_name'][@ng-model='entityData.name']")));
      entityName.clear();
      entityName.sendKeys("TEST");
  }
  ```

Comment: Is waiting for the element to be clickable instead of visible something peculiar to Angular?

Comment: @MateMrše _Thumb rule_, If your next step is to invoke `click()` or `sendKeys()` the only _ExpectedConditions_ for _Cross Browser_ is **`elementToBeClickable`** as `visibility` doesn't guarantees **clickability**

Comment: @DebanjanB, thanks very much, exactly as he told me.Thanks!!